# Linq to Sql Slow Performance on High Latency Connection

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

Analyzing a .NET executable performance some tasks are taking 30 secs - 1 minute from a WAN site, while the same operations complete in a few seconds from same site as SQL server. Note there is a high bandwidth available in WAN site to SQL server, but there is a big increase in latency (i.e. ping SQL server goes from 1-3 ms up to 50 ms)

Using a combination of tools packet capture, NProfile, .NET Reflector I've identified the task generates about 1,000 small SQL select statements. Further analysis shows that these are generated via Linq To Sql.

I am not the developer of the application and don't have access to the source code but need to provide feedback to development team on how performance can be improved.

Is there any recommended approaches with Linq To Sql to optimize performance for higher latency connections? Or would a different approach to accessing database be required?

There seems to be constant opening of new connections to SQL server which I suspect will be detrimental in a higher latency scenario.

Comment: "I've identified the task generates about 1,000 small SQL select statements." sounds like a classic N+1 query

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits this exact problem, but as I'm further analysing all the select statements being generated I can see the application is submitting the exact same query many times to the database. In addition after about every 2nd query it runs query "select 1" in function called TestDatabaseConnection

Comment: Without having access to source code or an example linq query it is hard to analyze the performance of your queries